# Filter Datatables after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I'm working in CodeIgniter and i have a DataTable, i want to filter the data from the DT after the ajax has been called. I'm trying to do that by filtering the table, but it's not working.

**Here's the JS Code.**

```
 $(function () {
   var tableRep=  $("#tblreport").dataTable({
       responsive: true, filter:true, order: [[ 1, "desc" ]],
            processing: true, serverSide: true,
            ajax: { "url": baseurl+"reports/Report/dataTable", "type": "POST" },
            columns:
            [
              {data:"idReport",},
              {data:"date"},
              {data:"customer"},
              {data:"status",visible:false},
              {data:null,searchable:false,orderable: false,width:"120px", render: function (row)
              { if (row.status == "wait") {return '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#report">Asign</a>'; }
              else  if (row.status == "process")  {return '<a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#report">Edit</a>';} else return '';} }
           ],
           columnDefs:
           [
             { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 1 },
             { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -1 },
             { responsivePriority: 3, targets: 2 }
           ], fnCreatedRow: function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
             if ( aData["status"] == "ready" ) { $('td', nRow).css('background-color', '#BEF781'); }
             else if ( aData["status"] == "wait" ) { $('td', nRow).css('background-color', '#F2F5A9'); }
             else { $('td', nRow).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF'); }
       }})
      });
var filteredData = tableRep.column(4).data().filter( function ( value, index ) {return value!="cancel" ? true : false;} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this option?

```
var tableRep=  $("#tblreport").dataTable({
    //your config
})
.on('draw.dt', function () {
     //Add here yours filters
 });
```

Comment: Here you can find a more detailed explanation, https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw, but basically this event is triggered everytime the table draw something